# Azure Pipeline: Visual Studio version '16.0' not found. Falling back to version '17.0'

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines

We keep getting the above warning whenever a build runs. Other than the warning it runs fine.

How can I make it go away (much as it makes me chuckle a bit in it's nonsense way)?

The pool for the build is this...

```
pool:
  name: Azure Pipelines
  vmImage: "windows-latest"
```

Is there something I can put in to force latest VS? / Something I can update so it doesn't try the old one and fail?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The setting you are looking for is `vsVersion` in the [`VSBuild@1`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/reference/vsbuild-v1?view=azure-pipelines) section.

In my case I switched it from `16.0` to `17.0` to avoid this warning, but according to the linked article the value `latest` is also available and should be what you asked for. `latest` is also the default, so you could also omit the entry.

> #vsVersion: 'latest' # 'latest' | '17.0' | '16.0' | '15.0' | '14.0' | '12.0' | '11.0'. Visual Studio Version. Default: latest.